# How to more effectively plot points in ggplot2 by groups if they overlap?

Tags: r

So, I would like to plot points using ggplot separated by groups, but because they overlap the colour by group function doesn't seem so effective visually, I already set the alpha to 0.3. What else could I do?

Comment: Try `facet_wrap()`!

Comment: a [mcve] would be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c((1:10)-0.05, 1:10, 1:10), y = c(1:10, 1:20), group = paste('Group', 1:10))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = unique(df$group))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = group), alpha=0.3)+
  geom_point()
```

So, as suggested by @Duck you can plot the points in separate plots using `facet_wrap` as in the following:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c((1:10)-0.05, 1:10, 1:10), y = c(1:10, 1:20), group = paste('Group', 1:10))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = unique(df$group))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~group)
```